# How automatically find out unused css in an html page and delete them?

Tags: css, uncss

I want to have an automatical way to find unused CSS in a static HTML page (no javascript, all CSS code are embedded) and delete them.

I currently manually search for the unused CSS. But this is not efficient. It seems that there is not such a way yet. But I want to doublecheck to make sure.

EDIT: A standalone command line tool is preferred.

Comment: This might help: https://medium.com/officialrajdeepsingh/how-to-find-unused-css-in-the-website-54d773d76b65

Comment: Could you provide an easy-to-use answer for it? Some of the answers found in the link assume the separation of HTML and CSS. But in my case, CSS is embedded in HTML. A standalone command line tool is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. **purify css**

use this tool at this link: https://purifycss.online/

> It searches through the HTML files and the given CSS files, it removes redundant CSS styles and writes the purified CSS to another file, then re-links the HTML files to the purified CSS file.

[image]

---

---

#### 2. **coverage - devtools**

there is functionality on devtools called "coverage"

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/coverage/

that make you see how many bytes are used,

 and how many aren't.

[image]

you can also use it to see what selectors aren't useful!

[image]

> the blue lines means: CSS is used
>
>  the red one means: CSS isn't used

---

as mentioned by @quentin

the pseudoelements, pseudoclasses are red by default.

so try to debug the normal CSS with this dev tools tool.

> also for debugging you need to use first the app, then see what CSS you really used for the things, and debug.
>
>  I tried now: if you use the website also `:active`, `:hover` not become red

---

---

#### 3. **make CSS to CDN**

the tool that I suggest you is [**`jsdelivr`**](https://www.jsdelivr.com/)

**why cdn?**

- **cache:** that makes your CSS cachable for a year,

  - so you install the CSS to the device, and then the device will not install it anymore.

     saving time, and network resources.
  - there isn't any code to do, it automatically does it for you.
- **minify:** the CSS code will be minified,

  - so spaces and tabs will be deleted
  - the code will be only in one line.
  - long variables, became one character vars.
- **simple:** you can make every Github or npm file a CDN easily.

   like this: `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/user/repo@version/file`

Comment: Isn't that just manually checking by hand still?

Comment: This even marks red for pseudo elements like `:focus`, :`active`, etc.

Comment: @geeky yes, he need first to use the app like a normal user, then check the coverage, and see what code is used at the end, and what not. yes isn't that good, but still, helps the developer to see what isn't used at the end.

Comment: OP wants to remove the unused CSS, if all the red ones are marked "unused", and removed, then all the pseudo elements get deleted

Comment: he can use logic in his program, that don't delete the `::after` and pseudoelements. something like this `if(isRed && !isPseudoElement) { /* delete code */ }` maybe solve this bug

Comment: But this does not automatically delete the unused css.

Comment: Then, this is not relevant to my question. Please delete the answer.

Comment: if you want automatic use `purgecss` and a cdn creator like `jsdeliver` that can minify the code something lke this style.min.css

Comment: cdn is not needed. I just have a standalone HTML with CSS embedded. Using a cdn for this problem is overkill.

Comment: @user1424739 ok. I find you a solution. use this tool https://purifycss.online/ , is simple and work for jsyt html and css

Comment: But it requires html and css be separated. In my case, CSS is embedded in HTML. Is there a place I can paste HTML code, so that I will have URL to serve on purifycss.online via the URL based method?

Comment: ok, I reread your comment, and I understand. copy the CSS inside the `<style>` tag and paste it inside it. or paste the HTML with the style="" attribute and see if it solve it. ..... however if you want a command line tool there is `purgecss` a tutorual about it https://blog.bitsrc.io/4-ways-to-remove-unused-css-647828ca629b#7ae9